# LWC - Refresh contents inside a single <lightning-tab>

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-tab, lightning-tabset, lightning-card

I have a component (**container**) with a lightning-tabset with a single lightning-tab.  Inside the tab is a component (**dataComponent**) which pulls "Item" records via Apex and assigns them to a tracked variable - @track contextRecords = []. Each Item in that variable appears as a card.  In that same **dataComponent** is a modal, which is shown conditionally when the "Add Item" button is clicked.

Inside each card there is a **dynamicRecordForm** component.  That component is a simple text input field, a Save button, and a Cancel button. Once a value is entered into the field and the Save button is clicked, the native *createRecord* from the lightning/uiRecordApi library is called, creating a new Item record.  An event is triggered, which passes the newly created record (stringified since it isn't officially accessible via Apex yet) up to the **dataComponent**.

In the *refreshTab* function in **dataComponent** the newly created record is parsed into an object, then added to the initial tracked variable - contextRecords.

Example: When the component loads, one Item record is retrieved via Apex and displayed as a single card within the tab.  The Add Item button is clicked, displaying the modal with the dynamicRecordForm.  A new Item name is entered and the Save button is clicked.

*Expected results*: The new Item record is added to the database and to the contextRecords variable, which then displays a new card for a total of two on the tab.

*Actual results*: A new Item record is added to the database, but nothing happens on the tab.  Only one card shows still.

If I refresh the entire page, however, the new card displays as it is retrieved via the initial Apex callout.

Any solutions?  I can't find anything in the documentation, developer forums, or StackExchange forums on this.

**SEE CODE BELOW:**

container.html:

```
<template>
    <lightning-tabset variant="scoped" active-tab-value="1">
        <lightning-tab>
            <c-data-component></c-data-component>
        </lightning-tab>
    </lightning-tabset>
</template>
```

container.js:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class Container extends LightningElement {}
```

dataComponent.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-layout>
        <lightning-layout-item size="12">
            <template for:each={contextRecords} for:item="contextItem">
                <div key={contextItem.Id} class="customCard">
                    <article class="slds-card">
                        <div class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner topSpace">
                            <c-dynamic-record-form onrefreshtab={refreshTab} oncancel={cancel}></c-dynamic-record-form>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </template>
        </lightning-layout-item>
    </lightning-layout>

    <div class={modalClass}>
        <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true"
            class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open modal">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" aria-label="">
                    <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close" alternative-text="Close" class="closeIcon"
                        onclick={closeModal}></lightning-icon>
                </button>
                <div class="slds-modal__header">
                    <h1 class="slds-modal__title slds-hyphenate">Add Item</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                    <c-dynamic-record-form onrefreshtab={refreshTab} oncancel={cancel}></c-dynamic-record-form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        
        <div class="centered">
            <lightning-button-group>
                <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Add Item" onclick={addItem}></lightning-button>
            </lightning-button-group>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

dataComponent.js

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';
import getItems from '@salesforce/apex/Item_Controller.getItems';

export default class DataComponent extends LightningElement {
    @track contextRecords = [];
    modalClass = 'slds-hide';

    connectedCallback(){
        this.getContextItems();
    }
    
    getContextItems(){
        getItems()
        .then(existingItems => {
            this.contextRecords = existingItems;
        })
    }
    
    addItem(){
        this.modalClass = '';
    }
    
    cancel(event){
        this.modalClass = event.detail.modalClass;
    }
    
    refreshTab(event){
        // this gives us a new record, Id included
        let newRecord = JSON.parse(event.detail.newRecord);
        this.contextRecords.push(newRecord);
    }
}
```

dynamicRecordForm.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-layout>
        <lightning-layout-item size="12">
            <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                <lightning-input type="text" label="Enter Item Name" data-name="nameField">
                </lightning-input>
            </div>
        </lightning-layout-item>
    </lightning-layout>
    <lightning-layout>
        <lightning-layout-item size="12">
            <div class="centered">
                <lightning-button-group>
                    <lightning-button label="Cancel" onclick={cancel}></lightning-button>
                    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Save" onclick={save}></lightning-button>
                </lightning-button-group>
            </div>
        </lightning-layout-item>
    </lightning-layout>
</template>
```

dynamicRecordForm.js

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { createRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

export default class DynamicRecordForm extends LightningElement {
    itemName;
    
    save(){
        let nameField = this.template.querySelector(`lightning-input[data-name="nameField"]`);
        let itemName = nameField.value;         
        let fields = [];
        field['Name'] = itemName;
        
        // code for adding default values is here, but irrelevant to this example
        
        const recordInput = {
            apiName: 'ItemObject',
            fields: fields
        };
        
        createRecord(recordInput)
            .then((record) => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Success',
                        message: 'Item created successfully!',
                        variant: 'success'
                    })
                    
                    this.cancel();
                    
                    // newRecord below is stringified because, though the object is created with an id,
                    // the async nature hasn't completed the commit to the database, making it inaccessible
                    // to Apex
                    
                    let event = new CustomEvent('refreshtab', {
                        detail: {
                            refreshTab: true,
                            newRecord: JSON.stringify(newRecord)
                        }
                    });
                    this.dispatchEvent(event);
                )
                .catch(error => {
                    this.spinnerDivClass = 'slds-hide';
                    this.dispatchEvent(
                        new ShowToastEvent({
                            title: 'Error creating ' + this.objectLabel + ' record',
                            message: error.body.message,
                            variant: 'error'
                        })
                    )
                })
            }
        
        cancel(){                       
            let event = new CustomEvent('cancel', {
                detail: {
                    modalClass: 'slds-hide'
                }
            });
            this.dispatchEvent(event);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest editing your question to add your actual code - at least the relevant parts of it.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the typos, you are probably running into problems because the `createRecord` method imported from `lightning/uiRecordApi` returns a object with a different shape and properties than a record pulled from a SOQL query in apex and sent to a lightning component.

For example, from Apex an sObject will have a parameter `Id`, but from `createRecord` you get `id`. There are many other differences besides that. When I used your example code above (after fixing many typos) and I pulled out the ID from the record returned by `createRecord` and put it into an object like `{Id: record.id}` and returned that as the record in the `refreshtab` event, I was able to get the record to show up dynamically after the event fires.

Comment: Hey Kyle, thanks for the response.  You're correct, 2, 3, and 4 were typos from me trying to greatly simplify my code example to fit on the page. :-)  However, #1 didn't fix the issue. :-(  Any other thoughts?  (I corrected the code in the post to fix the typos)

Comment: @AdamDrissel I updated my answer above. I believe the problem is most likely because createRecord returns an object with different properties than your apex method.